# Is there a standard resource for Material Design that I can compare a design against?

Tags: design-principles, resource-recommendations, google-material-design

I'm starting a project and I want to create a mockup using Material Design principles. Is there a good resource out there that outlines the principles so I can compare my design against it?

Answer (score 3):

Google has a guide that covers all areas of material design: [Material design - Google design guidelines](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html)